# Finding multiple indexes but the array always has a length of 1

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This seems trivial (again) but has me stumped.

I need to find the indexes of multiple values in a numpy array.  I can do this with `where` and `isin` but the resulting answer always has a length of 1 regardless of how many indexes are found.  Example

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]
b = [1,7,13]

x = np.where(np.isin(a,b))

print(x)
print(len(x))
```

this returns

```
(array([0, 3, 6]),)
1
```

I think its because the array is a single item inside a tuple.  How do I return just the array?

Comment: `where` returns a tuple, one array per dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
x = np.where(np.isin(a,b))[0]
```

to get what you expect.
As hpaulj points out in the comments `where` returns a tuple with one array for each input array dimension, in this case there is only one, which is why `x` is a tuple of length one.

Comment: thanks that answers the question.  If you don't mind could you explain hoiw the added  [0] changes the output?  I can't see a similar example in `np.where` pages

Comment: In the 'Note' box of [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) it is stated, that the documentation 'covers only the case where all three arguments are provided' and says that it is the same as `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` if only the first argument is provided, which is the case in your example.
And the documentation of `nonzero` states that a tuple is returned. To access the first and only argument of the tuple you can use `[0]`.
I hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: By the way it also advises you to just use `nonzero` in such a case: `x = np.nonzero(np.isin(a,b))[0]`

Comment: But in SO question and answers we use `where` far more often than `nonzero`. By the way, the tuple works just fine as an index.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, true, thanks for the addition. I was actually just citing the documentation, not personal preference. And yes the tuple will work as an index, but he did't say what he is gonna use it for (maybe some further calculations), so I thought this would be the 'safer' option :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to explain (of course its an index value duh!).  In case it matters, the indexes find values to ultimately write to an excel sheet, but bing a single tuple means all values where written to a single cell.